# Appending Arguments to the end of command module in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I want to write an Ansible role to be able to configure Kafka Topic.
I want to use a dictionary of Kafka topic properties and their values and use the `command` module in Ansible to create the topic.
For instance, use `default_kafka_topic` list:

```
---
default_kafka_topic:
    partitions          :
    - "6"
    replication-factor  :
    - "2"
```

to create a topic with attributes listed above.I have done the following to loop through the attributes and create a key/value pair. 
And then use the dictionary in the `command`.

```
- set_fact:
    dafault_kafka_topic_properties_dicts: |
        {% set res = [] -%}
        {% for key in default_kafka_topic.keys() -%}
           {% for value in default_kafka_topic[key] -%}
            {% set ignored = res.extend([{'topic_property': key, 'value':value}]) -%}
           {%- endfor %}
        {%- endfor %}
        {{ res }}

- name: Create Default Topic
  command: "{{ kafka_bin_dir }}/{{ kafka_topic_script }} --zookeeper {{ prefix }}-kafka-{{ Kafka_node }}.{{ DNSDomain}}:{{ zookeeper_port }} --if-not-exists --create --topic topic_name --{{ item.topic_property }} {{ item.value }}"
  with_items: "{{ dafault_kafka_topic_properties_dicts }}"
  register: createdTopic
```

However, this will not append the `topic_property` and `value` arguments to the end of the `command`. Instead the `command` is executed per argument.

Is there a way to append the key/value pairs as arguments to the `command` module and execute when the list is complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to loop in the same way as what you do in the above `set_fact` task, but print the values instead of creating a dictionary.

Maybe even instead of that task:

```
- name: Create Default Topic
  command: "{{ kafka_bin_dir }}/{{ kafka_topic_script }} --zookeeper {{ prefix }}-kafka-{{ Kafka_node }}.{{ DNSDomain }}:{{ zookeeper_port }} --if-not-exists --create --topic topic_name {{ properties }}"
  register: createdTopic
  vars:
    properties: |-
      {% for key in default_kafka_topic.keys() %}
      {% for value in default_kafka_topic[key] %}
       --{{ key }} {{ value }}
      {%- endfor %}
      {%- endfor %}
```

<sup>If you want to process the `dafault_kafka_topic_properties_dicts` instead of the original data, modify the loop accordingly.</sup>

Comment: Great, that was the solution. I should have thought of that.